# PowerShell -split on Pipe Character

Tags: regex, powershell, split

Consider the ASCII text file `test1.txt`:

```
a,b,c
d,e,f
```

And the following Powershell Script `test1.ps1`:

```
$input -split "`n" | ForEach-Object {
    $row = $_ -split ","
    $row[0]
}
```

The output is, as excpected:

```
a
d
```

However, if we change the separator to `|` everything fails as in `test2.txt`:

```
a|b|c
d|e|f
```

And the following Powershell Script `test2.ps1`:

```
$input -split "`n" | ForEach-Object {
    $row = $_ -split "|"
    $row[0]
}
```

The output is all but empty. Why does the `-split` fail?

Comment: NB: you can use import csv like this for do the same without your problem like this :       import-csv test1.txt -Delimiter "|" -Header col1, col2, col3 | select col1

Answer (score 8):

It seems `-split` expects a regular expression and thus you need to escape the pipe as in:

```
$row = $_ -split "\|"
```

Or specify the `SimpleMatch` option to split on the literal string or character:

```
$row = $_ -split "|", 0, "SimpleMatch"
```

The `0` stands for MaxSubstrings: "The maximum number of substrings, by default all (0)."

Source: http://ss64.com/ps/split.html
Also: [`Get-Help about_Split`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847811.aspx)